# Ansible: ansible-playbook not keeping double quotes when copying to a remote file

Tags: ansible

I am currently trying to copy a config file (YAML) to a raspberry pi using ansible-playbook. the problem is, ansible doesn't seem to keep the quotes from my config which is problematic since there are numbers represented as strings in it.

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: Update PIs configs
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  remote_user: pi

  tasks:
      - name: Check if the config directory exists
        stat:
            path: "~/.config/argos"
        register: argos_folder
      - name: Create the directory if it didn't already exist
        file:
            path: "~/.config/argos"
            state: directory
            mode: 0755
        when: not argos_folder.stat.exists
      - name: Create the config file.
        copy:
            content: '{{ config }}'
            dest: /home/pi/.config/argos/argos_config.yaml
```

I am passing the variables `hosts` and `config` via the cli:

```
ansible-playbook ~/ansible_playbook.yaml -i ~/hosts --extra-vars "@./vars.yaml
```

vars.yaml:

```yaml
hosts: testprofile
config: |
  default-settings:
    apn: test.com
  tests:
    sms:
      active: true
      endpoint:
        - "123123"
    call:
      active: false
      endpoint:
        - "123" 
    tcp:
      active: false
      endpoint: []
```

The command runs fine, but the copied content:

```yaml
default-settings:
    apn: test.com
  tests:
    sms:
      active: true
      endpoint:
        - 123123
    call:
      active: false
      endpoint:
        - 123
    tcp:
      active: false
      endpoint: []
```

on the pi, as you can see, is missing the double quotes for the `endpoint` arrays.

Is there a workaround to force ansible to keep those double quotes when copying the content ?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior: if I run you playbook with your vars file, the generated file preserves the double quotes. Can you tell us more about your environment (e.g. ansible version, os version of the control host, etc)? Can you reproduce the problem with this exact playbook, or does your actual playbook look different?

Comment: ...because if this is what your playbook actually looks like, why bother making `config` a variable? Just make it a file (`config.yml`) and use the `copy` module to copy it to the remote host.

Comment: I am connecting via SSH to an ec2 instance that has a reverse tunnel to the pis. the first connections happens in nodejs with the [ssh2](https://npmjs.com/ssh2) module. I am writing a new config.yaml each time, because of parameters sometimes changing between the different groups. I ended up generating the file on the instance and then copying it (with the copy module in the playbook).

Comment: Note: your first task is an overkill. Just keep the second one without the condition. You'll get the exact same result (i.e. ok / changed) with a bonus: mode of directory will be aligned if someone changed it manually since your last visit.